# problems with sql update using form data

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-update

I am trying to update records in a sql table.
I have followed a tutorial got everything doing as it should
but when I check to see if the record has been updated its not
I think it is a problem with this line of code, that is throughout the update page.

```
<td>
<input name="first" type="text" id="first" value="<? echo $rows['first']; ?>" size="22">
</td>
```

little bit more data as requested:

```
    $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>

<table>
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="update_ac.php">
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Update data in mysql</strong> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>First Name</strong></td>
<td><strong>Lastname</strong></td>
<td><strong>Address</strong></td>
<td><strong>Email</strong></td>
<td><strong>Username</strong></td>
<td><strong>Password</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td>
<input name="first" type="text" id="first" value="<? echo $rows['first']; ?>" size="22">
</td>
<td>
<input name="last" type="text" id="last" value="<? echo $rows['last']; ?>" size="30">
</td>
<td>
<input name="address" type="text" id="address" value="<? echo $rows['address']; ?>" size="40">
</td>
<td>
<input name="email" type="text" id="email" value="<? echo $rows['email']; ?>" size="30">
</td>
<td>
<input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername" value="<? echo $rows['myusername']; ?>" size="30">
</td>
<td>
<input name="mypassword" type="text" id="mypassword" value="<? echo $rows['mypassword']; ?>" size="20">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>
<input name="id" type="hidden" id="id" value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
```

What happens is results are returned in a table, you click to edit the entry
and are taking to this page where the fields are pre populated with the data
you are then supposed to make edits and update

when I update the field it seems like it does not carry the change forward

any help appreciated and if I have not explained it correctly sorry guys

code for update

```
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// update data in mysql database 
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET last='$last', first='$first', address='$address', email='$email', myusername='$myusername', mypassword='$mypassword' WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully updated. 
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='list_records.php'>View result</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}

?>
```

Comment: Could you add a little more code, please? Where is `$rows` being defined? Is it updated in the database, but not on the webpage? Not updated at all?

Comment: this line only shows the content of `$rows['first']` (as "echo" is expected to do), you have to add some logic to read the value and submit the changed value to database. Its programming not magic ;)

Comment: I am following this tut http://www.phpeasystep.com/mysql/9.html

Comment: @georgemason - could you also add the code you're using for the update, too?

Comment: @georgemason - thank you. Are you doing any debugging on that insert? Is it running properly? You're using a few variables when you build the statement - are they properly defined? Can you echo out the statement you're generating, and run it directly in the database?

Comment: is the $id coming to the update_ac.php?

Comment: @andrewsi not doing any debuggin as I am kind of a newbie to this

Comment: @aris the $id comes from the intial result return its hidden

Comment: @georgemason - you can look in the database to see if the row is updated; you can also `echo $sql` to see what your UPDATE string looks like

Comment: As I say I followed the Tut but even when I just went the exact same as the tut I could not get it to work

Comment: @andrewsi where would I put the Echo $sql at ?

Comment: @georgemason - just before the `$result=mysql_query($sql);` line.

Comment: @andrewsi ok added that returned SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id='1'

Comment: @andrewsi it prepoulates the input field with the data but does not seem to let me change the data, even though i can input into it and submit

Comment: @andrewsi this is result from update record using echo UPDATE customers SET last='', first='', address='', email='', myusername='', mypassword='' WHERE id=''Successful

Comment: @georgemason - there's your problem - none of those variables are being set. Do you need to populate them from $_POST?

Comment: @georgemason $id must be set somehow, with $_POST. I don't see this.

Answer (score 0):

You're making the query:

```
$sql="UPDATE $tbl_name SET last='$last', first='$first', address='$address', email='$email', myusername='$myusername', mypassword='$mypassword' WHERE id='$id'";
```

In the scope of that code's execution the variables you are passing do not exist. I'm guessing you want to pull them out of the $_POST array.

I should just mention as an aside, this is a very bad idea (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Consider using PDO and prepared statements instead.

```
$db = new PDO("mssql:host=$host;dbname=$tbl_name, $user, $pass");
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE $tbl_name SET last=:last, first=:first, address=:address, email=:email, myusername=:myusername, mypassword=:mypassword WHERE id=:id");
$stmt->bindParam(":last", $last);
$stmt->bindParam(":first", $first);
```

and so on…until

```
$stmt->execute();
```

Read more on PDO here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Or tutorial here: http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html

Comment: have now tried this way as well now and does not seem to work either

Comment: It won't work until you pass the posted values into the variables you are binding to the query. You need to set $last = $_POST["last"] etc.